# angularjs daterangepicker calendar shows Incorrect date

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using an [angularjs-daterangepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-daterangepicker) in my angularjs application. And as you can see from the below picture the dates are showing wrong.

```
   <button type="button"
       ng-click="$ctrl.DateRangeChanged()"
       date-range-picker="$ctrl.durationDateRange"
       ng-model="$ctrl.date"
       options="$ctrl.options" >Customize
   </button>
```

And the date range options are as follows

```
this.options = {
  pickerClasses: 'custom-display', // angular-daterangepicker extra
  buttonClasses: 'btn',
  applyButtonClasses: 'btn-primary',
  cancelButtonClasses: 'btn-danger',
  locale: {
    applyLabel: 'Apply',
    cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
    customRangeLabel: 'Custom range',
    separator: ' - ',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', // will give you 2017-01-06
    // format: "D-MMM-YY", // will give you 6-Jan-17
    // format: "D-MMMM-YY", //will give you 6-January-17
  },
  timePicker: true,
  autoApply: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
  startDate: (moment()).startOf('day'),
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must add date-range-picker-options in your input

```
<button type="button"
       ng-click="$ctrl.DateRangeChanged()"
       date-range-picker="$ctrl.durationDateRange"
       ng-model="$ctrl.date"
       date-range-picker-options="$ctrl.options" >Customize
   </button>
```

Comment: if you look at the calendar the may 1st date is wrong. option just works fine here

Comment: startDate: (moment()) can you pass start date like this

Comment: that doesn't have any impact.